# Dynamic objects creation in PHP

Tags: php, object, constructor

I made custom framework with some core files and models in 'model' directory. Now I'm create objects from models only when I need it and that works. But I want to create objects from all models classes automatically. For instance there is three models classes in 'models' directory,

```
//-----------[ ObjectOneModel.php ]-------------------
class ObjectOneModel
{
}
//-----------[ ObjectTwoModel.php ]-------------------
class ObjectTwoModel
{
}
//-----------[ ObjectThreeModel.php ]-------------------
class ObjectThreeModel
{
}
```

and one main controller

```
class Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    { 
        $files  = scandir('models/');
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]{1}[A-Za-z]*Model.php/', $file))
            {
                $object_name    = str_replace('Model.php', '', $file);
                $class_name     = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
                $this->{$object_name} = new $class_name();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works fine but for example ObjectThreeModel needs access to ObjectOne because data from ObjectOne are use in ObjectThreeModel. I figured that I'll create new object there

```
//-----------[ ObjectThreeModel.php ]-------------------
class ObjectThreeModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $ObjectOne = new ObjectOneModel();
    }
}
```

but I think that this is ugly solution because there is two same objects in memory. I need to find way to say to constructor which objects I need in created object, and constructor will pass this objects as parameters to himself? That is hard to describe but I hope You will understand my problem.

Comment: Pass a parameter to the constructor of the object you want this object to have access to i.e `public function __construct($otherObject){ $objectOne = $otherObject}`

Comment: Also, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php.

Comment: AbraCadaver, I'm using autoload in my projects already, there is not point of my problem, but thanks for help :-)

Comment: RiggsFolly, can you write more? How it works?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ugliness of your current approach is the fact you're scanning the entire model directory and loading whatever it finds. Instead, you should consider using some type of factory pattern to load objects as needed. Reference:

- [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)
- [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming))

Simple example:

```
class SimpleFactory
{
    public function build($model)
    {
        $obj = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\models\\' . $model . '.php';
        if (class_exists($obj)) {
            return new $obj();
        }
    }
}

class Controller 
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->factory = new SimpleFactory();
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        // this method has a dependency
        $oneModel = $this->factory->build('oneModel');
    }
}
```

This is cleaner because you're only loading objects as you need them. You could further revise this to suit your exact needs.